# Define different bounds for a multidimentional stochastic variable in pymc

Tags: python, pymc

I'm having an issue with defining bounds for a multidimentional stochastic variable.
Here is a dummy exemple to explain my problem.

If I want to have a 3 dimension discrete uniform between [0,100]

```
import pymc as mc
from numpy import empty

truth = mc.DiscreteUniform("bin1", lower=0, upper=100, value=[50,50,50], size=3)

@mc.deterministic(plot=False)
def unfold(truth=truth):
    out = empty(3)
    for r in xrange(3):
        out[r] = truth[r]
    return out

data = [5, 10, 30]
unfolded = mc.Poisson('unfolded', mu=unfold, value=data, observed=True, size=3)
model = mc.Model([unfolded, unfold, truth])                             
mcmc = mc.MCMC( model )
mcmc.use_step_method(mc.AdaptiveMetropolis, truth)
mcmc.sample(10000,1000,10)
```

this will sample a DiscreteUniform for 3 bins with the same range for each bin (between 0 and 100).

Now, I tried several things to define different range for each bin, but can not succeed. I tried arrays of DiscreteUniform and arrays of bounds (upper,lower), but they obviously does not work.

Does anyone ahs any idea how to define different range for the various bins of a stochastic variable?

Answer (score 0):

To define different ranges and initial values you need to call the stochastic constructor N times to create a list of variables and then use the Container constructor to make the list pymc-readable:

```
bin1 = mc.DiscreteUniform("bin1", lower=0, upper=100, value=50, size=1)
bin2 = mc.DiscreteUniform("bin2", lower=0, upper=40, value=20, size=1)
bin3 = mc.DiscreteUniform("bin3", lower=10, upper=50, value=30, size=1)
truth = mc.Container([bin1,bin2,bin3])
```